# Bootstrap Popover is not working on last row

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover, bootstrap-popover

I am using [Bootstrap popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers). It doesn't show on last row.
I am using jquery [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function to loop.

Here is the code:

```
HTML:
<table id="Tableid" class="table " >
</table>


JS:

var table = $('#Tableid');
var hostId = 1;
var count = 0;
var row = $('<tr></tr>').addClass('test');
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){            

    for(j=0; j<3; j++){

        var button = "<button data-content = \""+hostId+"\" data-id=\""+hostId+"\"class=\"btn btn-primary btn-lg open-InfoModal\" data-toggle=\"modal\" rel=\"popover\" data-target=\"#hostInfo\" href=\"#infoModal\"></button>";
           $("[rel='popover']").popover({trigger: "hover"});

        var cell = $('<td style="text-align:center">'+hostId+'</td>').addClass('test').wrapInner(button);    //We use wrapInner to add HTML content
        hostId++;
        row.append(cell);
    }
    if(count<1) {
        count++;
    } else {

    table.append(row);
    row = $('<tr></tr>').addClass('test');
    count = 0;
    }
}
```

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zfpD8/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This**

```
var table = $('#Tableid');
var hostId = 1;
var count = 0;
var row = $('<tr></tr>').addClass('test');
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){            

    for(j=0; j<3; j++){

        var button = "<button data-content = \""+hostId+"\" data-id=\""+hostId+"\"class=\"btn btn-primary btn-lg open-InfoModal\" data-toggle=\"modal\" rel=\"popover\" data-target=\"#hostInfo\" href=\"#infoModal\"></button>";

        var cell = $('<td style="text-align:center">'+hostId+'</td>').addClass('test').wrapInner(button);    //We use wrapInner to add HTML content
        hostId++;
        row.append(cell);
    }
    if(count<1) {
        count++;
    } else {

    table.append(row);
        row = $('<tr></tr>').addClass('test');
        count = 0;
    }
}

$("[rel='popover']").each(function(i, e){
    $(e).popover({trigger: "hover"});
});
```

**Check it here** [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zfpD8/8/)

Answer (score 1):

Move this line to the end of the script, outside of for loops:

```
$("[rel='popover']").popover({trigger: "hover"});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slash197/zfpD8/7/)